# How to add "my translation" to a reference

Tags: biblatex

I write my thesis in English but quote a Danish report and hence have to translate the quotes myself.

I am using <strike>APA 6th</strike>`biblatex` and would like an output like

> (Allerup 2012, p. 11, my translation)

How can I add the "my translation" part?

`biblatex` is called with

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxbibnames=99, date=year, sortlocale=danish,
  firstinits=true, style=authoryear-icomp, dashed=false,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=true,]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You can always say `\cite[my translation]{xyz}`.

Comment: With `biblatex` you would write `\parencite[\pno~11, my translation]{allerup}` (and `\ppno` for several pages as in `\parencite[\ppno~11--14, my translation]{allerup}`) with `natbib` probably something like `\citep[p.~11, my translation]{allerup}`. What bibliography package and style are you using?

Comment: Do you use the `apacite` package and bibliography style? Please advise.

Comment: One more for `biblatex` abusing the multi-postnote argument `\parencites(my translation)[380]{sigfridsson}` (note the **`s`** in `\parencites`). Even though it works it is probably not really sound semantically speaking.

Comment: @moewe, using your \parencites solution did the trick. Thanks a lot. How can I mark, that this solved my problem?

Comment: @all: Thanks for your comments, questions and advices. I am unsure if I answer the question about package and style correct, but I am using biber. I wrote I use APA 6th, but it appears I am going a bit loose on that, since I actually use this:  \usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,date=year,sortlocale=danish,firstinits=true,style=authoryear-icomp,dashed=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=true,]{biblatex}

Comment: The piece of information about biblatex and biber being in use is definitely crucial.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for instructing me. I shall remember that.

Comment: I have edited your question accordingly, hope that is OK.

Comment: @Mico Edited the question to include the info about `biblatex`, of course that somehow makes your answer less relevant, so feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: @moewe - Nah, am happy to upvote your answer. :-)

Comment: @moewe: Absolutely. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `biblatex` [as confirmed in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439727/how-to-add-my-translation-to-a-reference?noredirect=1#comment1104263_439727) you can use

```
\parencite[\pno~380, my translation]{sigfridsson}
```

or for several pages

```
\parencites[\ppno~378--380, my translation]{sigfridsson}
```

`\pno` is used for single pages, `\ppno` for (ranges or sequences of) several pages, even if the string is the same in your document language it is a good habit to use the correct form.

Here the `\pno`/`\ppno` is necessary to display the "p."/"pp." prefix that is normally inserted automatically when a pure page range is present because `biblatex` only adds the prefix for page ranges to avoid unfortunate output such as

> *see Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. and references therein

The MWE below shows two other methods to obtain a similar result. `\pagespostnote` has the advantage of also formatting page ranges nicely. The `\origpostnote` has the additional advantage of using the active `postnote` format which can be beneficial if the format of the postnote is changed with `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}`.

With a bit of abuse of the `multipostnote` you can also try

```
\parencites(my translation)[380]{sigfridsson}
```

which has the advantage of not needing the extra `\pno`/`\ppno` because the page range is in an argument of its own. But that is not exactly syntactically clean, because the `multipostnote` in round brackets normally refers to all citations in a multi-cite command, and here arguably only the specific source to which the arguments in square brackets belong is relevant.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand*{\pagespostnote}[1]{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
\newcommand*{\origpostnote}{\printtext[postnote]}

\begin{document}
\parencite[\pno~380, my translation]{sigfridsson}

\parencites[\ppno~378--380, my translation]{sigfridsson}

\parencites[\pagespostnote{380}, my translation]{sigfridsson}

\parencites[\pagespostnote{378-380}, my translation]{sigfridsson}

\parencites[\origpostnote{380}, my translation]{sigfridsson}

\parencites[\origpostnote{378-380}, my translation]{sigfridsson}

\parencites(my translation)[380]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(updated this answer after learning from the OP that he/she uses biblatex and biber, not BibTeX and the `apacite` package)

If one uses the `apacite` package with the `natbibapa` option and the `apacite` bibliography style, and it the citation key of interest were `a:2012`, all one would have to to do is write

```
\citep[p.~11, my translation]{a:2012}
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
% create a dummy bib file
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{a:2012, author = "Allerup", year = 2012, title = "Thoughts"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citep[p.~11, my translation]{a:2012}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico. I found Moewe's suggestion to use \parencites easier for me, since it is similar to the \parencite which I already use.